# Switch off the status line at bottom of Centos 9 shell

Tags: shell, centos

I'm running a minimal install of CentOS 9 Stream and accessing it only via ssh.  A problem that I haven't seen before with CentOS 6, 7 or 8 is that there is now a status line displayed at the bottom of the shell console displaying things like time, date, hostname etc as you can see in the picture below:
[image]

This is very annoying because it provides me with no information I need but prevents the scrollback buffer from operating correctly.  I haven't got tput or screen installed.  Does anyone know how to switch this off?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `screen` is not installed somewhere?

Comment: Totally @thring.  Checked with dnf and its not listed.  I even installed screen (and it successfully installed indicating it wasn't there before) and tried to instruct it not to display the status line but with no effect, so I've uninstalled it again.  So unless CentOS 9 (minimal install with guest services and the NIST CUI security policy) has screen embedded but obfuscated (which would be rather odd) then it definitely isn't installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've got to the bottom of this now.  It isn't GNU screen and is tmux that is implemented as part of the NIST 800-171 security profile.  This has enabled me to switch the status line off:

```
tmux set -g status off
```

To enable the mousewheel to operate scrollback correctly I have just added the following to `/etc/tmux.conf` :

```
set -g mouse on
```

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity Actually this is the OP posting the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is an artifact of [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), called the status line, or hardstatus in the screen config (.screenrc) file.

If you're not familiar with GNU Screen, it is actually a very handy utility, that you can get an introduction to here: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/

If you look in your `.screenrc` file in your home directory, you ought to be able to turn off that status line by changing `hardstatus alwayslastline` to `hardstatus ignore`.

Or maybe you can build yourself a better status line, using some inspiration:

- http://beerpla.net/2009/10/06/supercharge-your-gnu-screen-with-a-power-taskbar-and-never-feel-lost-again/
- https://www.kilobitspersecond.com/2014/02/10/understanding-gnu-screens-hardstatus-strings/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Tim. I’m still a bit confused though because screen definitely isn’t installed (check via dnf).  There is no .screenrc but l I’ll create one and try your suggestion though in case it has been a bit obfuscated in this version of CentOS.  Because it interferes with the scroll back buffer I just want to get rid of it.

Comment: Tried it and this isn't the cause Tim :-( There was no effect creating the .screenrc so I installed screen and the .screenrc file was actioned but it just displayed the following and did nothing to remove the status line:
^[[>0;10;1c[pmyd@localhost ~]$ 0;10;1c
-bash: 0: command not found
-bash: 10: command not found
-bash: 1c: command not found

Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: You are absolutely running screen, that’s standard output, and your complaint about scroll back is another clue that it is in a screen session.  If the package isn’t installed remotely, are you sure you aren’t running screen on the local side?  Does “control-a c” create another terminal on the local system or remote?

Comment: Hi @jsbillings, I thought so too.  However, I installed it to try to follow Tim's advice, and then uninstalled it when it didn't solve the problem, and regardless every attempt to use .screenrc to remove the status line has failed.  Ctrl-A C doesn't do anything.  I'm remoting in from Windows using OpenSSH in Powershell so it isn't the remote system.  I'd really love to be wrong because I could then resolve the problem, but can't understand how it can be screen